# Не загружается ОС Windows после заполнения системного тома

Tags: windows, загрузка, ос, ssd

Есть Kingston NV1 PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD. В процессе записи в системный том на нем закончилось свободное место и ОС зависла, после перезагрузки ПК система отказывается загружаться (выдает зеленый экран с надписью в духе "у вас сломалось - перезагрузите пк"). После перезагрузки винда начинает процесс восстановления который не приводит ни к какому результату. Пробовал грузиться с LiveCD, но тут возникает самое интересное: В биосе мой ссд определяется нормально (пробовал на нескольких ПК), однако при загрузке системы не видно разделов данного диска, в прочем, как и его самого. Проверял через AIDA64 - программа видит контроллер ssd на pci плате. В victoria - программа видит устройство, но не может его проверить, так как не может получить паспорт устройства. Если пробовать загрузиться из под установщика windows, то диск тоже не отображается. Как можно заставить отображаться тома на диске или же хотя бы отформатировать диск, чтобы им можно было снова пользоваться?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй переустановть ОС. Сохранив фалы диска "С". Это врят ли свяазано с заполнением тома. или в терминале попробуй `sfc /scannow` ля проверки ОС на повреждения. Диск "С"заполнен?

Comment: Я не могу переустановить ОС, так как при загрузке с установочной флешки и начала установки на моменте выбора диска для установки там нет диска

Comment: Да, диск "С" заполнился, на Д сколько то места было, >50Гб

Comment: Так же diskpart не выдает ни разделы ни тома, а при выводе дисков то видно диск на котором все значения в 0